# Speck32 with low-entropy messages

Tags: speck

I'm using Speck 32 to encode a very low-entroy set of bits (so that the messages stay very short)

It encodes two numbers:

- w: 16 bits: but in most circumstances the message is one of only 10-100 possibilities (~3-7 bits)
- v: 8 bits, but in most circumstances the message is only about 4 bits

In my current scheme, I use random (throw-away) content for the last 8 bits. My questions are as follows, assuming a message set in the low thousands (I.e. an attacker would have access to ~4000 encrypted messages):

1. Even with the low entropy, are the messages individually secure (i.e. the compromise of some doesn't undermine the security of the others)?
2. Can successful guessing/statistics across a large enough set of messages compromise the key?
3. There's a temptation to use the last 8 bits for a MAC and/or CRC, but I fear that would make statistical attacks even better. Is that fear warranted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I hear you correctly, you are trying to solve the problem of securely transporting $w$ and $v$ values, under the constraint of minimizing the ciphertext size.

So, what you're doing is taking the $w$ and $v$ values, selecting a random $r$ value, concatinating them into a 32 bit block, and then sending that block through Speck32 (with some key with unspecified derivation), and that's you're ciphertext.

With that procedure, I see these possible attacks:

- Someone brute forces the key; Speck32 has a 64 bit key.  While brute-forcing the key would be beyond the capability of a random hacker, it would be within the capabilities of a determined large organization.  If your threat model requires you to be secure against such large adversaries, it's not good enough.
- Someone recovers the key in another way.  You don't say how you keys are exchanges, but if (for example) you have a global key that everyone uses, then if someone breaks in one device, and grabs the key, then he has everyone's keys.
- Looking for repeated values.  If someone sees the same ciphertext twice, then he knows the $w$ and $v$ values are repeated (and $r$, but he doesn't care about that).  Assuming that $r$ is generated randomly, then you are likely to see a repeat after perhaps 16 repeats of $w, v$ values.
- Modifying the ciphertext block; if the attacker is able to modify the ciphertext, he can modify it to a value to a value he hasn't seen (which would cause the decrypted $w, v$ values to be effectively random).  Alternatively, he could modify it to be a ciphertext he has seen before (in which case, the decrypted $w, v$ values will be what we sent before.

So, to answer your questions:

> Even with the low entropy, are the messages individually secure (i.e. the compromise of some doesn't undermine the security of the others)?

Well, assuming that the attacker can't do a key recovery attack, then the best he can do is look for repeated values.  If he does see a repeat, and he knows the value in one case, he obviously knows the value in the other.  This doesn't tell him anything about any other ciphertext.

> Can successful guessing/statistics across a large enough set of messages compromise the key?

No, it doesn't help the attacker.  If he has the resources, he can perform the brute force attack on a handful of messages (assuming he can recognize plausible $w, v$ values); more ciphertexts doesn't help him.

> There's a temptation to use the last 8 bits for a MAC and/or CRC, but I fear that would make statistical attacks even better. Is that fear warranted?

Well, if you have a fixed value there (dependent on $w, v$), that increases the probability of a repeated ciphertext.  Also, if you go with using $r$ as the authentication, I wouldn't bother doing a CRC or a MAC on $w, v$; those are already stirred into the ciphertext.  What I would do is either use fixed bits (say, 0; those are easy to generate/verify, and is no less secure than a function of $w, v$), or if you want to add some protection against copy/paste attacks, make $r$ a function of the ciphertext context (e.g. a function of the message sequence number), and have the decryptor check it.  Now, it's not great (a random change would still have a 1/256 chance of being accepted), but it's better than nothing).

Some final comments:

- One thing you need to worry about is key distribution; that's quite often the Achilles heel of crypto systems.  The best crypto system doesn't help if you make it easy for the attacker to learn the keys
- Might I suggest you consider using Speck48?  Not only does it allow larger keys (making brute force attacks considerably harder), but it allows the $r$ value to be 16 bits larger; if you select $r$ randomly, this means that practically speaking repeated ciphertexts won't happen; if you select $r$ as a function of the message context, that means that a change will have a very good probability of being detected.  Of course, that means that you'll have 16 more bits to transmit; you'll need to decide whether that's a viable option.